# Umbraco preview not working

Tags: umbraco

When I change content of our web site from umbraco and try to preview it is not working. This is because the required umbraco js and css files are not loaded. Our site is hosted in a IIS virtual directory(eg: /localhost/mySite)

The correct path should be for the umbraco files should be,

```
http://localhost/mySite/umbraco/assets/css/canvasdesigner.css
```

but the js and css file paths are taken as,

```
http://localhost/umbraco/assets/css/canvasdesigner.css
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with relative URL's within Umbraco - you should try setting up your web site as a new web site in IIS with a new record in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a change to your /config/umbracoSettings.config

Add true under  in the umbracoSettings.config file in the config folder.